# How can I insert json results into a WordPress table?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, wordpress

I have a custom page in WordPress that generates a json and I'd like to do an insert into a custom table that is in the WordPress database. How can I do this?

```js
{"horarios":[{"dia":"2017-10-25","hora_inicio":"17:00","hora_termino":"17:00"},{"dia":"2017-10-26","hora_inicio":"13:30","hora_termino":"16:00"}]}
```

Thanks.

Comment: why the custom page doesn't put the datas in the database directly ?

Comment: json object can be of datatype Varchar. So it can be inserted just like any varchar value

Comment: The results are in javascript/json, I'm not sure how I could pass these values to be inserted in the same custom page.

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself to do this? This isn't a coding or tutoring service. Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and your relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To Insert Data Of Table Into Wordpress Custom Table.**

**step 1: convert mysql table to json file** 
https://www.csvjson.com/sql2json

**step 2: export table and paste into https://www.csvjson.com/sql2json**

```
/**
 * Continents 
 */
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `continents`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `continents`;
CREATE TABLE `continents` (
  `code` char(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Continent code',
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of continents
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `continents` VALUES ('AF', 'Africa');
INSERT INTO `continents` VALUES ('AN', 'Antarctica');
INSERT INTO `continents` VALUES ('AS', 'Asia');
INSERT INTO `continents` VALUES ('EU', 'Europe');
INSERT INTO `continents` VALUES ('NA', 'North America');
INSERT INTO `continents` VALUES ('OC', 'Oceania');
INSERT INTO `continents` VALUES ('SA', 'South America');
INSERT INTO `continents` VALUES ('??', NULL);
```

**step 3.create directory data**

**step 4. put json file into data directory.**

**step 5: put the bellow code into plugin main plugin file or anywhare eles.**

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'plugin_name_install_data');

function plugin_name_install_data()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'continents'; 

    $contactjsondata = file_get_contents(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'data/continents.json');
    $data = json_decode($contactjsondata, true);

    foreach ($data['continents'] as $single_data) {

        $item=array(
            'code'=> $single_data['code'],
            'name' => $single_data['name']
        );

        $result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $item);

    }
}
```